# Extract info from a string using some predefined words

Tags: php, arrays, string

I guess the title is pretty abstract.

So I have some arrays that contains an adress(here is an example):

```
array(4) { ["cod"]=> int(200) ["message"]=> string(7) "SUCCESS" ["found"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["cui"]=> int(655485) ["data"]=> string(10) "2017-04-21" ["name"]=> string(13) "Example SA" ["address"]=> string(64) "JUD. NEAMT, SAT ROMEDC ALEXANDRE COM. COMENKA, STR. EXAMMS RANTEM, NR.6" ["tva"]=> bool(true) ["data_sfarsit"]=> string(1) " " ["data_anul_imp"]=> string(1) " " ["mesaj"]=> string(31) "platitor de TVA la data cautata" } } ["notfound"]=> array(0) { } } Array ( )
```

So what I want is to extract from ['address']  , the word after 'JUD.'--(that would be `NEAMT` , then I want the words after 'SAT' --(that would be `ROMEDC ALEXANDRE`  , then I want the words after 'COM.' --(that would be `COMENKA`) then I want the words after 'STR.' -- (that would be `EXAMSS RANTEM`).

Basicaly , from an 'address' string , I want to put each info in separate columns (STR being Street , NR. being the number of the house , SAT would be the village/town)

Also , 'address' will have different strings each time like 'BL.' (building) or 'AP.' -- apartment number(not all addresses have an AP number).

How can I achieve what I want? Thank you.

Comment: can you share `print_r($array)`?

Comment: @SahilGulati that would be a print_r of an json_decode, thats where the array comes from.  Array ( [cod] => 200 [message] => SUCCESS [found] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cui] => 5435345 [data] => 2017-04-21 [denumire] => EXAMPLE SA [adresa] => JUD. NEAMT, SAT ROMEDC ALEXANDRE COM. COMENKA, STR. EXAMMS RANTEM, NR.6 [tva] => 1 [data_sfarsit] => [data_anul_imp] => [mesaj] => platitor de TVA la data cautata ) ) [notfound] => Array ( ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you out..

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/780167)

```
<?php
$string='JUD. NEAMT, SAT ROMEDC ALEXANDRE COM. COMENKA, STR. EXAMMS RANTEM, NR.6';
$result=preg_split("/(?:JUD.\s*|\s*SAT\s*|\s*COM\.\s*|\s*STR.\s*)/", $string);

array_walk($result,function($value,$key) use (&$result){
    if(stristr($value, ","))
    {
        $result[$key]=explode(",", $value)[0];
    }
});
print_r(array_filter($result));
```

Comment: Its really interesting. Thanks alot. The single problem is that the first result from the array has the comma at the end resulting --> 'NEAMT,' while the others don't. What can I do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "JUD. NEAMT, SAT ROMEDC ALEXANDRE COM. COMENKA, STR. EXAMMS RANTEM, NR.6";

$JUD = substr($str, strpos($str, "JUD. "), strpos($str, ", SAT") );
$SAT = substr($str, strpos($str, ", SAT "), strpos($str, ", STR.") );
$STR = substr($str, strpos($str, ", STR. "), strlen($str) );
```

Comment: I want to get 'COM.'  too -- that does not have any comma before it. Also , the order of these might be different each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know more about the possible variations in your input.  Please extend your question to include 4 or 5 different possibilities so that I can test/refine my process.

Input:

```
$string='JUD. NEAMT, SAT ROMEDC ALEXANDRE COM. COMENKA, STR. EXAMMS RANTEM, NR.6';
```

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eed33054ed64db36546955d8fd58990486f9a31b)):

```
$all_markers=['JUD.','SAT','COM.','STR.','NR.','BL.','AP.'];     // list all possible markers
$escaped_markers=preg_replace('/\./','\.',$all_markers);         // prepare dots for regex pattern

$pattern='/(?<= |^)(?:'.implode(' ?|',$escaped_markers);         // declare all markers as match start points
$pattern.=' ?).*?(?= '.implode('| ',$escaped_markers).'|$|,)/';  // declare all match end points

if(preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$out)){
    foreach($out[0] as $pair){
        list($key,$val)=preg_split('/(?:'.implode('|',$escaped_markers).')\K ?/',$pair,2);
        $result[$key]=$val;
    }
    $desired_markers=['JUD.'=>'','SAT'=>'','COM.'=>'','STR.'=>''];  // list as keys the marker=>data you want
    $result=array_intersect_key($result,$desired_markers);        // filter out undesired marker=>data
    var_export($result);
}else{
    echo '$pattern failed';
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  'JUD.' => 'NEAMT',
  'SAT' => 'ROMEDC ALEXANDRE',
  'COM.' => 'COMENKA',
  'STR.' => 'EXAMMS RANTEM',
)
```

Because you say that the desired values in the string can be in any order, it is necessary to capture the keyword/marker so that you can accurately associate the values with its marker.  Is this not true?

Comment: @an4rei Please provide some more input samples, so that I can test/refine my method.  It may seem a bit messy, buy I am trying to design my code to be very flexible -- easy to add/remove markers and desired data.